# upload file to another directory laravel 5

Tags: file, laravel, upload, directory, file-handling

I want to store my uploaded file in A specific folder and not in de storage/app folder.

```
public function upload(Request $request) {
        $files = $request->file('file');
        foreach ($files as $file):
         Storage::put($file->getClientOriginalName(), file_get_contents($file));

        endforeach;
```

I have tried to do this but it doesn't work:

```
public function upload(Request $request) {

        $selectfolder = \Request::get('selectfolder');
        $files = $request->file('file');
        foreach ($files as $file):
        storage_path(). "/download/". $selectfolder::put($file->getClientOriginalName(), file_get_contents($file));

        endforeach;
```

Laravel gives this error:
**syntax error, unexpected '::' (T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify location to saved first, then move file to that path

```
public function upload(Request $request) {
    // selected folder
    $selectfolder = \Request::get('selectfolder');
    // input files
    $files = $request->file('file');

    foreach ($files as $file):

        $fileName = $file->getClientOriginalName();

        $pathToStore = storage_path(). "/download/". $selectfolder;

        $file->move($pathToStore, $fileName);

    endforeach;
}
```